# quarto / knitr show code block including attributes

Tags: r, knitr, quarto

I'm writing a webpage on using quarto and I want to include code blocks, with the code attributes, for example:

````
```{r}
#| eval: false
teacher_df %>% 
  head(3)
```
````

but when I write this in a webpage it appears as so:

```
teacher_df %>% 
  head(3)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

`````
````markdown
`r ''````{r tables-mtcars}
knitr::kable(iris[1:5, ], caption = 'A caption')
```
````
`````

Comment: @eglease, please remove your edit, it's wrong. It's very important to see the code with at least 4x \` prior to r chunk. Otherwise the edited by you answer doesn't make sense. And \`\`\` markdown doesn't hurt.

Comment: Done.  Sorry about that.  It looked like bad formatting during the review.